# Is it possible to go to edit view of SP2010 item directly from email?

Tags: workflow

**Question Posted by other user:**
Is it possible to go to the edit view of an sharepoint 2010 list item directly from email? I have a workflow that sends an email to a user to edit a list item. The link -at this time- takes them to the list. I would like for the link to take them to the edit view of that item. thanks,

**Answer Posted by other user:**
Use Sharepoint Designer:

In the body of the form "send an e-mail", find 'edit hyperlink' button in the upper right corner of the message.
for field address, click lookup for string or 'fx' 
in Data Source, select “Workflow Context”. for field from source, select "Current Item URL".
Now Save, publish and test.

Unless I am doing something wrong, this does't put you in the EDIT view.  Can anyone else shed a little more light on this?

Comment: I don't know how they do it but the approval workflow opens the task up in outlook.

Answer (score 3):

Use that menu, but craft the url to point to EditForm.aspx?ID=[currentitemid] or use a build dynamic string action before you email the user to build up a url to the editform with ID=[currentitemid].

This will take you to the editform and eliminate a mouse click.